# android save files into internal data folder

Tags: java, android, eclipse

My app saves some files into data/data folders on device. After saving that remote files, I handle that files copying them into other folders. All is working properly on all devices tested previously but on galaxy s3 generates a nullPointer exception. Seems that I am not allowed to write or handle files on that folder! but only with new galaxy s3! I am also not able to find any file on data folder using eclipse ddms file explorer while in simulator (same android version) I can see properly all app files! What can be different on galaxy s3? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**-** Thats the `Security` feature of Android.

**-** You can easily peek into the `data` folder of an Emulator, but **Not of an Android Phone.**

**-** If peeking into the data folder of an Android Phone was this easy, then anyone could get the access to the `DataBase, etc`

Till now i have tested this on `Galaxy S2` , `HTC Explorer`, `Galaxy Note`,  **all were NON-ROOTED.**

Comment: Ok, so do you mean that with new versions of Android I am not allowed to keep writing and handling files into data folder? What should I do instead? Use sd card folder? Does it mean that my apps that are fully handling files on "old" versions must be modified? Thank you

Comment: @You don't have the access to the data folder on your Android Physical device... You can store you filed on /sdcard/MyFolder, and its accessible